# Filling missing records with previous existing records

Tags: sql-server

I have an existing database where some logic is made by the front end application.
Now I have to make reports from that database and I'm facing to a proble of missing records which are covered on a record basis in the frontend but have issues in the report
Given the following tables:

```
create table #T (id int, id1 int, label varchar(50))
create table #T1 (id int, T_id1 int, A int, B int, C int)
```

With the values:

```
insert into #T values (10, 1, 'label1'), (10, 2, 'label2'), (10, 3, 'label3'), (10, 15, 'label15'), (10, 16, 'label16'), (20, 100, 'label100'), (20, 101, 'label101')
insert into #T1 values (10, 1, 100, 200, 300), (10, 15, 150, 250, 350), (20, 100, 151, 251, 351), (20, 101, 151, 251, 351)
```

if I make a report we can see some missing records:

```
select #T.id, #T.id1, #T1.A, #T1.B, #T1.C
from    #T left join #T1 on #T.id1 = #T1.T_id1
```

result:

```
id  id1 A   B   C
10  1   100 200 300
10  2   NULL    NULL    NULL
10  3   NULL    NULL    NULL
10  15  150 250 350
10  16  NULL    NULL    NULL
20  100 151 251 351
20  101 151 251 351
```

Expected result would be:

```
id  id1 A   B   B
10  1   100 200 300
10  2   100 200 300
10  3   100 200 300
10  15  150 250 350
10  16  150 250 350
20  100 151 251 351
20  101 151 251 351
```

As you can see here the missing data is filled out of the the first (in id, id1 order) previous existing record for a given id. For a given id there can be any number of "missing" records and for the given id there can be any number of existing records after a not existing ones.
I can do this with a cursor but I'm looking for a solution without cursor

Comment: is it possible that 2 different rows will have the same pair of id and id1 or I can treat these columns as unique?

Comment: No. The id, id1 pairs (and even id1 alone) is unique)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use subquery (to find groups with same values) + window function

```
WITH Grouped AS (
    SELECT #T.id, #T.id1, #T1.A, #T1.B, #T1.C, 
        GroupN = SUM(CASE WHEN #T1.A IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER(/* PARTITION BY id ? */ ORDER BY id1 ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM    #T 
    LEFT JOIN #T1 ON #T.id1 = #T1.T_id1
)
SELECT Grouped.id, Grouped.id1,
    A = MAX(A) OVER(PARTITION BY GroupN),
    B = MAX(B) OVER(PARTITION BY GroupN),
    C = MAX(C) OVER(PARTITION BY GroupN)
FROM Grouped
```

Comment: Seams to work (although without the partiton by clause). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use below sql for thedesired output:

```
with cte (id, id1, A, B, C)
as
(
    select #T.id, #T.id1, #T1.A, #T1.B, #T1.C
    from    #T left join #T1 on #T.id1 = #T1.T_id1
)
select cte.id, cte.id1, 
coalesce(cte.A,TT.A) A,
coalesce(cte.B,TT.B) B,
coalesce(cte.C,TT.C) C
from cte
left join
(
    select p.id1,max(q.id1) id1_max
    from cte p
    inner join cte q on p.id1 > q.id1 and p.a is null and q.a is not null
    group by p.id1
) T on  cte.id1 = T.id1
left join cte TT on T.id1_max = TT.id1
```