# T-SQL - Filling up records from previous periods

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, fill

I have data from a quarterly reporting for actions in a table. Branches report progress of actions or enter new actions on a quarterly basis.

```
ReportingPeriod   Company   ActionId  Action                Budget    State
2022-03           Alpha     1         Cleaner Produktion    10        prepared
2022-03           Alpha     2         New Backbone           5        ready
2022-03           Alpha     3         IT Security           20        ongoing

2022-06           Alpha     1         Cleaner Produktion    12        prepared
2022-06           Alpha     3         IT Security           20        ready
2022-06           Alpha     4         New Office chairs      2        prepared

2022-09           Alpha     1         Cleaner Produktion    12        prepared
2022-09           Alpha     4         New Office chairs      2        ongoing
```

Problem: When an action gets the status "ready" in one quarter, this action is not carried forward to the following quarter. See action 2 from Q1 to Q2 or action 3 from Q2 to Q4.

However, for evaluation and reporting, I need all actions per quarter, including those completed in previous quarters (their data set from the last reported quarter), so like this:

```
ReportingPeriod   Company   ActionId   Action              Budget   State
2022-03           Alpha     1          CleanerProduktion   10       prepared
2022-03           Alpha     2          New Backbone         5       ready
2022-03           Alpha     3          IT Security         20       ongoing
2022-06           Alpha     1          Cleaner Produktion  12       prepared
2022-06           Alpha     2          New Backbone         5       ready
2022-06           Alpha     3          IT Security         20       ready
2022-06           Alpha     4          New Office chairs    2       prepared
2022-09           Alpha     1          Cleaner Produktion  12       prepared
2022-09           Alpha     2          New Backbone         5       ready
2022-09           Alpha     3          IT Security         20       ready
2022-09           Alpha     4          New Office chairs    2       ongoing
```

Since I need the data live and cannot trigger a stored procedure, I would need this as a view.

Comment: I have assumed you are using SQL Server here. If you are using a different product that uses T-SQL, such as Azure SQL Database, Sybase, or Azure Synapse, please [edit] your question to correct the tag(s).

Comment: I solved the problem with the answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44761286/filling-missing-records-with-previous-existing-records